# Subquery is taking much longer then normal

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle10g, query-optimization

I encounter a problem with optimization.

When I use a query like this:

```
Select * (around 100 columns)
from x
where RepoDate = '2020-05-18'
```

It's taking around 0.2 seconds.

Unless I'm using query like this:

```
Select * (around 100 columns)
from x
where RepoDate = (select max(RepoDate) from y)
```

It takes around 1 hour.
Table  `y` has only dates (2020-05-17, 2020-05-18, ... )

Can you tell me why there is so much difference in time to execute?

Comment: `'2020-05-18'` is not a `DATE` to begin with, as it is a string. Secondly, `SQL Developer` is a tool, not sure what it has to do with the performance of your query. Thirdly, we neither have your `table/data` nor any `explain plan` or `performance metrics` to tell why your query is *slow/fast/whatever*?

Comment: We cannot give an answer until you provide more details. Please read [this excellent post on asking Oracle tuning questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325).

Comment: How may rows are in `Y`? How many in `X`? What are the two execution plans?

Comment: Can you supply an Explain plan for queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you are comparing a simple first query with a query having another subquery that might be processing a heavy table "y" already.

So these two queries are not the same to start with. We need to have explain plans to have an estimation of the cost of the subquery first (i.e. how many rows, index usage etc.) then we move to the parent query.